# Where is a complete list of MIME types with codecs for the HTML5 source attribute?

Tags: html, html5-video

The HTML 5 `source` element has a `src` and a `type` attribute, like this:

```
<source src='url' type='mime/type; codec="codec-name"' />
```

Where is a complete list of the MIME types for the type attribute, together with their corresponding valid codecs attribute values?

Answer (score 11):

There is a great [list of MIME types and their browser support along with the codecs at WHATWG Wiki](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/Video_type_parameters#Browser_Support).

The most common codecs used and supported for HTML5 video are:

- **WebM:** audio/webm, video/webm
- **OGG:** application/ogg, audio/oggm, video/ogg
- **H.264 or MP4:** audio/mp4m, video/mp4

So, you can set the `<source>` for your video to read:

- `<source src="video.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>`
- `<source src="video.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"'>`
- `<source src="video.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="vc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>`

As you can see, the MP4 is the trickiest, as you have to know which codec you're using and the AVC level for the video stream. The one I list above is a common one, but not the only possible one.

Comment: Jennifer, you really should have given proper credit to diveintohtml5.org for you source options--you basically copied and pasted and just changed the file name. That's bordering on plagiarism unless your name is Mark Pilgrim.

Comment: @Dane: These strings could be copied from anywhere, not just http://diveintohtml5.org/video.html. For example, look at the page linked by Jennifer, they also include these type strings.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann, I want to compress the video, What should I do? I am using this mimetype mimeType: "video/webm; codecs=vp9". Is it ok?

Comment: @JaynaTanawala Please don't ask questions in comments. Use the blue "Ask question" button on the top of the page. (Though your question needs to be a bit more elaborate to be answerable, I gusss.)